# Pushing an Apple ID for App Store to IPads with Apple Configurator

Tags: apple-id, ipados, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

Is there a way to push an Apple ID to the iPads with profiles via Apple Configurator?

I have several 100 and would like to push it so we do not have to enter it manually for each.